# Tabulator - load and save data

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am new to programming. I want to create a client-server application in which the user saves to a file on the server and loads data from a file on the server into the Tabulator table. But I don't know how to save the data to the server and download the data from the server. Also I do not know on what the server has to be (php, sqlserver..).
There is a Tabulator(js) library.
Please help I am newbie (VS2019, IIS):

- where should I exactly place the json file to load into the table?
- how can I create a new json file and save it in the project folder using the Tabulator tool (IIS using the built-in one)
- how can i load my json file via ajax into a table?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.